# How to combine two <xsl:if test> conditions in xslt to check if both nodes exist at the same time?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
  <xsl:if test="string(oai:record/oai:metadata/easydb:objects/easydb:objekttyp/easydb:_nested__objekttyp__contributor/easydb:objekttyp__contributor/easydb:person/easydb:person_urheber/easydb:custom[@name=&apos;orcid&apos;]/easydb:string[@name=&apos;url&apos;])!=''">
            <xsl:if test="string(oai:record/oai:metadata/easydb:objects/easydb:objekttyp/easydb:_nested__objekttyp__contributor/easydb:objekttyp__contributor/easydb:person/easydb:person_urheber/easydb:custom[@name=&apos;gnd&apos;]/easydb:string[@name=&apos;conceptURI&apos;])!=''">                                               
            <xsl:for-each select="/oai:record/oai:metadata/easydb:objects/easydb:objekttyp/easydb:_nested__objekttyp__contributor/easydb:objekttyp__contributor">
              <dc:contributor>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(easydb:person/easydb:person_urheber/easydb:name[@type=&apos;text_oneline&apos;] ,&apos;, &apos;, &apos;ORCID: &apos;, easydb:person/easydb:person_urheber/easydb:custom[@name=&apos;orcid&apos;]/easydb:string[@name=&apos;url&apos;] ,&apos;, &apos;, &apos;GND: &apos;, easydb:person/easydb:person_urheber/easydb:custom[@name=&apos;gnd&apos;]/easydb:string[@name=&apos;conceptURI&apos;] ,&apos;, &apos;,&apos;(&apos;,easydb:rolle/easydb:person_rolle/easydb:name[@type=&apos;text_l10n_oneline&apos;]/easydb:de-DE,&apos;)&apos;)" />
              </dc:contributor> 
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:if>
          </xsl:if>
```

I want to make a condition if both strings exist then concatenate following parts. It's even enough to check if both nodes exist at the same time. The problem is that two if test conditions don't work. Should they be combined in one condition?

It should be checked if `<easydb:string name="url">orcid.org/0000-8628</easydb:string>` exists
My original XML:

```
<record xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" xmlns:easydb="https://schema.de/EAB/1.0/objects/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <header>
                <identifier>oai:b5-45c0-8ad4-8f5c3964bcdb</identifier>
                <datestamp>2018-11-14T09:50:51Z</datestamp>
                <setSpec>objecttype_pool:objekttyp:pool:2</setSpec>
                <setSpec>pool:1</setSpec>
                <setSpec>tagfilter:cc</setSpec>
                <setSpec>objecttype:objekttyp</setSpec>
            </header>
            <metadata>
                <easydb:objects base-schema="207" instance="lar" timestamp="2019-03-01T18:24:30+01:00" user-schema="227" uuid="334655-8c3d-b71241bbc99b">


                    <easydb:objekttyp>
```

```
                            <easydb:person>

                                <easydb:person_urheber>
                  <easydb:_version>2</easydb:_version>


                                    <easydb:_id>2</easydb:_id>


                                    <easydb:_system_object_id>413</easydb:_system_object_id>


                                    <easydb:_standard>


                                        <easydb:de-DE>Man</easydb:de-DE>


                                        <easydb:en-US>asian</easydb:en-US>


                                        <easydb:und>Minian</easydb:und>


                                    </easydb:_standard>


                                    <easydb:name type="text_oneline">Man</easydb:name>


                                    <easydb:custom name="orcid" type="custom:base.custom-data-type-link.link">


                                        <easydb:string name="url">orcid.org/0000-8628</easydb:string>


                                        <easydb:string name="tld">org</easydb:string>


                                        <easydb:string name="hostname">orcid.org</easydb:string>


                                        <easydb:object name="_fulltext">


                                            <easydb:string name="string">orcid.org/00628</easydb:string>


                                            <easydb:object name="l10ntext">


                                                <easydb:string name="de_DE"/>


                                                <easydb:string name="en_US"/>


                                            </easydb:object>


                                        </easydb:object>


                                        <easydb:object name="text">


                                            <easydb:string name="de_DE"/>


                                            <easydb:string name="en_US"/>


                                        </easydb:object>


                                    </easydb:custom>


                                </easydb:person_urheber>


                            </easydb:person>


                            <easydb:rolle>


                                <easydb:person_rolle>


                                    <easydb:_version>4</easydb:_version>


                                    <easydb:_id>14</easydb:_id>


                                    <easydb:_system_object_id>579</easydb:_system_object_id>


                                    <easydb:_standard>


                                        <easydb:de-DE>ProjectBeteiligte</easydb:de-DE>


                                        <easydb:en-US>ProjectMember</easydb:en-US>


                                        <easydb:und>ProjectMember</easydb:und>


                                    </easydb:_standard>


                                    <easydb:name type="text_l10n_oneline">


                                        <easydb:de-DE>ProjectBeteiligte</easydb:de-DE>


                                        <easydb:en-US>ProjectMember</easydb:en-US>


                                        <easydb:und>ProjectMember</easydb:und>


                                    </easydb:name>


                                </easydb:person_rolle>


                            </easydb:rolle>


                        </easydb:objekttyp__contributor>



                    </easydb:_nested__objekttyp__contributor>
```

```
            </easydb:objects>
        </metadata>
    </record>
```

Comment: As far as you have added simple null check in both if conditions, there's nothing wrong doing it. You can combine as many conditions in `xsl:if` with `and` and `or` operators. If you can share your input source, it would be more easier to get to the issue.

Comment: @Vebbie just added the original XML

Comment: Why not use a <choose>?  And, in the first when, test for both strings != '', in the second when, test for the first string != '', and in the third when, test for the second string != ''.

Comment: @Bluewood66 I tried it with choose and when, but it doesn't work. Got the same output.